# Last Step to Set Up a Nginx Server with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, vps

I've been trying to set up an nginx server on my VPS to deploy my rails app.
Everything has been successful until the last command, and if I get this to work, I will be able to see my app on the server.

I did

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

and finally,

```
sudo update-rc.d uinicorn_app defaults
```

but it says

```
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/unicorn_app: file does not exist
```

I manually checked the file by going into the directory, and the file was there. However, when I ran the command below, I got the following.

```
deployer@max:/$ file /etc/init.d/unicorn_app
/etc/init.d/unicorn_app: broken symbolic link to `/home/deployer/apps/app/current/config/unicorn_init.sh'
```

How do I fix this issue and finish setting up my server?

**Update:** it seems like my *deploy.rb* config is not working properly because I cannot find /home/deployer/apps/app/current folder. Here's part of my **deploy.rb**:

```
namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, :roles => :app, :except => {:no_release => true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, :roles => :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the file `/home/deployer/apps/app/current/config/unicorn_init.sh` exist?

Comment: @bdares, there are only "releases" and "shared" folder in apps/app directory. How come current folder does not exist?

Comment: it turned out I forgot to do cap deploy:cold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't locate your current file, run

```
cap deploy:cold
```

which will deploy your application, run all pending migrations, and start the server for the first time.